# Calling a function and passing arguments from Kotlin to Flutter

Tags: android, kotlin, flutter, dart, flutter-platform-channel

I am dealing with `PlatformChannels` trying to communicate from `Kotlin` to `Flutter`. Trying actually to do what it is explained on the docs from flutter platform channels, but on the opposite direction:

[flutter platfor channels docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels?tab=android-channel-kotlin-tab#separate)

The idea is to call a Flutter function from the configureFlutterEngine function on the MainActivity.kt class.

For that, i do, **on Flutter side, main.dart** (default example from Flutter):

```
   class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  static const platformChannel = const MethodChannel('myTestChannel');


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    platformChannel.setMethodCallHandler((call){
      print("Hello from ${call.method}");
      return null;
    });


    //
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          //
          //
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And from the **Kotlin side**, i just try to call the flutter callback method on **MainActivity.kt**:

```
override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine)

        val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, "myTestChannel")

        channel.invokeMethod("myTestChannel","the argument from Android")
}
```

But nothing is printed on the Flutter side when I run the code. No crashes or exception either.

Comment: Don't call `setMethodCallHandler` from `build`; `build` will be called multiple times. Call it, instead, from `initState`. It's best to encapsulate all method channel code in a plugin project. The basic project that gets built when you create a plugin project contains an example and the Android (and iOS) code, which you can modify and extend. In particular, you'll see how to create the `MethodChannel` at the Android end, and you'll be able to call `invokeMethod` on it.

Comment: @RichardHeap, thanks for the suggestion, besides that, is it any other reason why the Kotlin side seems to not be calling the function in the Flutter side?

Comment: Your kotlin code doesn't look correct. You need to implement `FlutterPlugin` and create the method channel in your override of `onAttachedToEngine`. (Note that `onAttachedToEngine` is the new API, so many answers and documentation haven't been updated yet.)

Comment: @RichardHeap thank you so much I will give it a try, feel free to post an answer so I can accept it if you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be implement below way

Dart Code

method_channel_helper.dart

```
class AmazonFileUpload {
  static const platform = const MethodChannel('amazon');
  static StreamController<String> _controller = StreamController.broadcast();

  static Stream get streamData => _controller.stream;

  Future<BaseResponse> uploadFile() async {
    try {
      platform.setMethodCallHandler((call) {
        switch (call.method) {
          case "callBack":
            _controller.add("");
            break;
        }
      });
      final Map result = await platform.invokeMethod('s3_upload');
      return BaseResponse(result["success"], result["error"], "");
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      return BaseResponse(false, e.message, "");
    }
  }
}
```

home_page.dart

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    AmazonFileUpload.streamData.listen((event) {
      print("========$callbackFromKotlinToDart--------");
    });
    AmazonFileUpload().uploadFile();



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

}
```

Android Code

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity(), TransferListener {
    private val CHANNEL = "amazon"

    var methodResult: MethodChannel.Result? = null
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
        val channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)

        channel.setMethodCallHandler { call, result ->
            methodResult = result
            if (call.method == "s3_upload") {
                //Add you login here 
                channel.invokeMethod("callBack", "data1")



            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

This ended up working on my end. If you want to invoke your methods inside of android lifecycle callbacks, try something like this

```kotlin
const val CHANNEL = "yourTestChannel"

class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

  override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
  }

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    var flutterEngine = FlutterEngine(this)

    flutterEngine
      .dartExecutor
      .executeDartEntrypoint(
        DartExecutor.DartEntrypoint.createDefault()
      )

    var channel = MethodChannel(flutterEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL)

    channel.invokeMethod("yourMethod", "yourArguments")
    }
  }
}
```