# What is the name of the channel from Java/Kotlin to Flutter (not the way around)

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin

Flutter has the MethodChannel for sending data from Flutter to Java/Kotlin. We can also return values in these calls. But what if I want to return data at random times from Java/Kotlin to Flutter?

I remember there is a kind of channel to send data from Java to Flutter, but I forgot its name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calling a function and passing arguments from Kotlin to Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59823810/calling-a-function-and-passing-arguments-from-kotlin-to-flutter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EventChannel or MethodChannel can be used to pass data from flutter to android and android to flutter.
In your case android to flutter, you can read this blog:
https://testfairy.com/blog/native-communication-with-a-callback-in-flutter/

Also, similar question as to this have been answered previously :

[How to open and pass data from Native Android App to Flutter Android App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61832100/)

[How to send data to Flutter from native (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62035546/)